# How to get chat messages of a chat Id sent after a given time?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Following is the structure of `messages` node in my Firebase Realtime Database:

```
"messages" : {
    "-MDQs5CjIFbIPV24XSHX" : { // Group chat Id
      "-MDQt6gYsxrwislwSItN" : { // Message Id
        "_id" : "-MDQt6gYsxrwislwSItN",
        "chatId" : "-MDQs5CjIFbIPV24XSHX",
        "creationDate" : 1596048309540,
        "messageType" : "type_text",
        "senderId" : "cOEwux6gjpPoZSQ9h3PHcFz5X8g1",
        "senderName" : "User 1",
        "text" : "Hi"
      }
   }
}
```

In the `GroupChatFragment`, I want to retrieve messages pertaining to the Id of the group chat but only those that were sent after the user joined the group chat.

I know that it ain't possible with the current database structure because in that case I would be required to create index for messages/chatId/creationDate, and chatId is being created dynamically.

What sort of database structure can help me achieve this objective?
It would be really illogical to show a newly joined user all the messages since the inception of the group chat.

Comment: If you consider at some point in time to try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find a tutorial on how to create a complete and functional [Firestore Chat App](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb).

Comment: @AlexMamo Please suggest a suitable solution to this problem in Firebase Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do so by arranging group chat by time** i.e..in place of message id
**Then simply when someone is added,add time when that person is added in group in their group record**.. *And then, if time of group message arrival is greater then only show those message..*

Comment: Please update your answer by adding an appropriate Firebase query that supports your answer. Thanks!